# Moving graphics with keylistener/arrow keys

Tags: java, keylistener, arrow-keys

Hey guys i am trying to move a rectangle with arrow keys using keylistener in java. I got everything to work and imported everything but it is saying that the class name is not implemented in the non-abstract class "SoccerGame." I do not know what to do. I tried to make many changes to get it to work but it is still not functional. Are there any more packages I need to import or something? Hope you guys can help. Thanks.

```
// The "SoccerGame" class.
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SoccerGame extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    int x = 200, y = 200;


    public void init ()
    {
    this.requestFocus ();
    addKeyListener (this);

    setSize (800, 550);
    } // init method


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
    g.drawRect (20, 20, 340, 340);

    g.fillRect (x,  y, 20, 20);
    } // paint method

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y-10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y+10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x-10;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x+10;
    }

    repaint ();
    }

    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

} // SoccerGame class
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine after adding the missing `public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}` to avoid compilation error.